# Deleting array of strings

Tags: c++

Suppose I have an array of strings:

`string* item`

And this `item` array is dynamically constructed using `new` operator. How do I free up this dynamically allocated memory if the number of entries in the array is `numItems`?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::string>`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau A single delete[] for the whole array or should I loop through each element and use delete[]?

Comment: you have to delete with the subscript operator `[]`. `delete [ ] item`. but if the array is `std::vector` then the destructor of the vector  he destroy the lements by calling the destructor of each item in the vector

Comment: @Naveen You are not `new`'ing the individual strings, only `new[]`'ing the array, so there is only 1 `delete[]` needed

Comment: Strictly speaking, `string* item` is not an array. It is a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `new[]` to allocate the array, and `delete[]` to free it:

```
#include <string>

std::string* item = new std::string[numItems];
...
delete[] item;
```

A better option is to use `std::vector` and let it handle the memory for you:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> item(numItems);
```